# nginx reverse proxy working only if port 80 available

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I hope somebody can help me to solve/understand this issue as I am totally stuck.

I am a ec2 instance running nginx. This ec2 instance is behind a load balancer.

My nginx configuration, is to reverse the traffic to an external service hosted on azure.

But for demonstration purpose lets assume this external service is `example.com`

all my infra is working, and my nginx configuration files is like this:

```
# This is the new file
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        server_tokens  off; # disable the Server nginx header 

        # enable gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
            text/plain
            text/css
            text/js
            text/xml
            text/javascript
            application/javascript
            application/x-javascript
            application/json
            application/xml
            application/rss+xml
            image/svg+xml;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
            proxy_pass https://example.com;

        }
    }
    server {
        listen   443; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        server_tokens  off; # disable the Server nginx header 

        # enable gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
            text/plain
            text/css
            text/js
            text/xml
            text/javascript
            application/javascript
            application/x-javascript
            application/json
            application/xml
            application/rss+xml
            image/svg+xml;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
            proxy_pass https://example.com;

        }
    }
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

With this configuration everything works just fine. But if I remove the `server` on port 80 and keep only the `443` and reload nginx. On the browser I get the error `Bad Gateway`

Is the `server 80` required for nginx? I checked all the documentation and couldn't find anything.

Please can anyone enlighten me on this issue or just point me on the right path? thank you so much for any help you can provide or hint.

And please if my question is not 100% clear, don't hesitate to ask for details